# Use emulateapj/aastex with siunitx

Tags: siunitx, incompatibility, aastex

I am trying to use siunitx in an emulateapj document, however it reports a conflict of command:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined"
! 
! Command '\tablenum' already defined!
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

generate by pdflatex of the following document:

```
\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}
%\documentclass{aastex}
%\let\tablenum\relax
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\title{emulateapj with siunitx}

\author{Jerry Ma}

\begin{deluxetable}{rr}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablewidth{\the\columnwidth}
\tablecaption{\label{tab:test}
A dummy table}
\tablehead{\colhead{col1} &
\colhead{col2} \\
\colhead{\left(\si{\gram}\right)} &
\colhead{\left(\si{\milli\meter}\right)}
}
\startdata
 80.76 & 50.4 \\
 19.28 & 33.4 \\
\enddata
\tablecomments{siunitx doesn't work}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Naively I put the following just before I load siunitx:

```
\let\tablenum\relax
```

to solve the confliction.
This time it compiles through (means I can see the output pdf file which contains a table as expected)
but with errors like the following:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\lt@expand@linewidth@): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \begin{deluxetable}{rr}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.22 }

?
```

So, the question is, How could I make emulateapj to work with siunitx?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to me looks like 'you can't'. If you load the class and the `array` package (used by `siunitx`) you get the same `Illegal pream-token` error. The `array` package is part of the core LaTeX tools set, so not working here is a big problem. Probably the `deluxtable` environment has its own internals that are distinct from the standard `tabular` set up, which will break with `array`.

Comment: The `deluxetable` environment tweaks `longtable` in order to get tables as wide as the text column. Why would anybody do this is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with the aastex documentclass.  I was able to use the [savesym](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package as a workaround:

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{tablenum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\restoresymbol{SIX}{tablenum}
```

The savesym package is used to "redefine symbols where names conflict."  In this case, the conflict is with the `tablenum` symbol.

Note that this only solves the problem of siunitx trying to define a symbol that already exists.  There is another problem pointed out by Joseph Wright: the deluxetable environment is not compatible with the array package.  This is only a problem if one actually uses the deluxtable environment.

In order to use the deluxetable environment, I need to modify the environment as follows:

```
% redefine deluxetable for compatibility with the array package.
\let\oldenddeluxetable\enddeluxetable
\let\olddeluxetable\deluxetable
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{deluxetable}[1]{
\olddeluxetable{[#1]}
\def\pt@format{#1}%
}{\oldenddeluxetable}
\makeatother
```

This can be done right after the `\restoresymbol{SIX}{tablenum}`.  The redefinition changes `\def\pt@format{\string#1}%` from aastex.cls to `\def\pt@format{#1}%`.

There may still be some other issues lurking around, but so far these changes have worked for me.

Comment: Please explain what this code does. Suppose the reader does not know `savesym` ...